# Socket.IO connection error

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I've an application in node.js with socket.io. Everything was running completely fine, but suddenly the browser started to send this error.

> failed: Error in connection
>   establishment:net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED

I didn't make any code change.

The protocol used by socket is ws:// and when I try to use this url in browser

> 'ws://highgarden-nodejs-91180.sae1.nitrousbox.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=T9Unec8KbWw-GAL8AAAF'

Chrome returns this error:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_DISALLOWED_URL_SCHEME

This is a part of the socket setup code:

*server.js:*

```
    var app = express();
    var server = http.createServer(app);
    var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
    var port = process.env.PORT || 3000
*------------------------------------------*

    // routes ===
    var routes = require('./config/routes.js');
    var sock = {}
    routes(app, passport, sock); 
    io.sockets.on('connection', sock.update);

    // launch ===
    server.listen(port);
```

Thanks advance.

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: Did you use socket.io from client side to connect to server?

Comment: Yes. My actual code, without any change, already worked.

Comment: Do you fixed this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Hi the exception ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED happens when a tunnel connection through the proxy could not be established. And the ERR_DISALLOWED_URL_SCHEME happens when the scheme of the URL is disallowed.

May you need use it behind the proxy!

Comment: I try to use the 'match origin protocol' true (Meant to be used when running socket.io behind a proxy.) But still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome 45.0.2454.101 m says the page has been disabled or moved on the server.